# linux shell script in java

Tags: java, linux, shell

I am using below shell code in linux i want it to make it in Java.I want to call this command in JAVA

```
mailq | grep -B1 -i temporarily | grep -iv deferred | \
egrep -i 'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec' | \
awk -F" " '{print $1}' | awk '{print  substr($0,10,14)}'
```

mailq command shows the queued mail messages with there respective Id and there errors .
Like in command above i am looking for messages with temporarily disabled message in it and taking the above message where its id is present in  ********09089 like this checking the month and than printing the last 5 characters of that id

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what this command is supposed to do. On Ubuntu, I typed `man mailq` and got `No manual entry for mailq`. I know I can google it, but easing the work of those wanting to help can be a good idea... Here, you expect people to both know well mailq, awk, and Java (not JAVA, BTW). I am sure there are plenty of those people, but are they reading this question?

Comment: Thanks Philho
thanks for pointing that out highly apprecited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  String cmd = "mailq | grep -B1 -i temporarily | grep -iv deferred | "
              +"egrep -i 'jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec' |" 
              + " \'{print $1}\' | awk \'{print  substr($0,10,14)}\'";
    try
    {
      ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", cmd);
      Process p = pb.start();
      p.destroy();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Thanks Bitmap 
Is there any other way to call above command in JAVA ,since mailq command exists in Linux is there a command in JAVA equivalent to mailq command in Linux so that i can write this shell code in JAVA directly

Comment: There's no library for mailq Java.

Answer (score 3):

here 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score 0):

In general this type of issues is handled in java by 'Runtime' class.
Here [Runtime example java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)
you can find an example of how to do that

The newer approach would be using ProcessBuilder class though

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to do the same thing that this shell command, but in pure Java, not by running it from Java. One advantage of the port can be portability.

I think you want [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) to do the mail access. I am not a specialist of this API, but I used it in a small [Processing](http://Processing.org) program to show its usage: [Email sketch](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~philho/+junk/Processing/files/head:/_SmallPrograms/Email/).

Then you need to filter out the results and to isolate the part you want, which isn't very hard.