# Is There Any Way To Use Linux Commands in Java Directly

Tags: java, linux, grep

I want to use Linux grep in my java program for searching, because grep's performance is satisfying. But I don't want to call it with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` command from operating system. Therefore I downloaded grep-2.9 source code but now I don't know how I can integrate that code to my java app. Is there any way to use grep or other linux commands directly, not from OS?

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/using-grep-with-r-option-863794/

Comment: If you don't want to use Java's `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` frequently, just create a "grep server" in C, python, or some sane language and connect to it via a socket.

Comment: Take a look the following:  
[running a linux shell script from java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427951/linux-shell-script-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should better try this:[Grep4J](http://code.google.com/p/grep4j/)

Another possible alternative is to use groovy they have grep supported by the language library

Both of approaches are better then running linux specific utilities from Java.

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you explain please, why Grep4J is better then running linux specific utilities from Java? I want to remind that, performance is the most important thing in project I am working on.

Comment: If performance is that important then you wouldn't really be using java would you. Making system calls is neither performant nor portable hence avoided.